# Kafka : Manually assigned consumer unable to commit or close due to 'GroupAuthorizationException'

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka and spring-integration in the code-base; and am able to create an 'anonymous consumer' (manually assigned consumer) with unique group-id, able to retrieve list of messages to reprocess, and push those to a separate channel.

However - the problem occurs 'auto-committing' the offsets(when auto-commit on consumerfactory is true) and of 'closing' this  consumer created above. In both cases - the root exception is "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: random-groupid_ee10697f-e35f-4542-801c-1605620c59fa"

The 'auto-commit' fails with a **WARN** msg no doubt, but don't see any 'successful' commit msg thereafter. The 'close' operation fails too when exiting with error ('Failed to close coordinator', with end of stacktrace having 'Not authorized to access group: random-groupid_ee10697f-e35f-4542-801c-1605620c59fa'

Have tried committing explicitly in the code as using both sync and async commit calls; but no luck. However; when I try this manually commit;  the 'close' operation succeeds (even though commit failed); 
**OR** when we close explicitly using  consumer.close(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) )

Not sure what I am missing here - as I it seems very odd/strange that I'm able to 'create' a consumer with unique group-id and assign/seek manually on the topics, but I face authorization issue during 'commit' or 'close' operation on the same consumer. Everything else works perfectly fine..

Do I need to configure some specific property on the 'consumerFactory' in order for it to commit offsets correctly and close without this authorization error? Ideally, would like for the auto-commit = true to work as am not looking to handling commit of offsets manually for now.

Note: cannot use kafka-streams as underlying impl doesn't support it,have to go with this approach for now. have removed few utility methods and have tried to shorted code for brevity

Code:

```
 public void handle() {
        topicList.stream().forEach(topic->{
            try (Consumer<String, byte[]> consumer = (Consumer<String, byte[]>) consumerFactory.createConsumer("random_group_"+ UUID.randomUUID(),topic)) {

                List<PartitionInfo> partitions = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);
                long startTime = Instant.now().minus(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli();
                long endTime = Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli();
                //a map of TopicPartition objects to the time offset we want to START
                Map<TopicPartition, Long> map = createTopicPartition(startTime, partitions);
                //call consumer.offsetsForTimes and filter out null ones...
                Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsets = getFilteredTopicOffsets(consumer, map);

                for (Map.Entry<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> e : offsets.entrySet()) {
                    processPartitions(endTime, consumer, e.getKey(), e.getValue().offset());
                }
                LOG.debug("Exiting the reprocess stream... closing consumer.."+consumer);
                //below succeeds, but however we seem to be closing it without committing any offset
                consumer.close(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch(Exception exp) {
                LOG.error("Exception While reprocessing the events or closing the consumer", exp);
            }

        });//error is thrown here when the 'try-with-resources' completes and consumer.close is called internally.
        LOG.debug("Done...");
    }

    /**
     * Processor method starting from the supplied offset,  continues until with no more messages
     * are found or the timestamp of message is out of range (supplied endtime)
     */
    protected List<Message<?>> processPartitions(Long endTime, Consumer<String, byte[]> consumer, TopicPartition partition, long offset) {
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> currentOffsets = new HashMap<>();
        List<Message<?>> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        consumer.assign(Lists.newArrayList(partition)); //manually assign partition
        consumer.seek(partition, offset);           //seek to the supplied offset
        long currentRecordTime = 0;
        List<? extends ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> records;
        try {
            do {
                records = consumer.poll(2000).records(partition);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
                    //logic to retrieve record time of this record..
                    currentRecTime = getRecordTime(record);
//the below snippet for currentOffsets is ideally avoidable. have only tried this as auto-commit is failing with the same 'groupAuthorizationException.. HOwever, this approach fails too
                    currentOffsets.put(
                            new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                            new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset()+1, null));
                    if (currentRecTime < endTime) {

                        Message<?> message = new MessagingMessageConverter().toMessage(record, null, null);
                        messages.add(message);
                        LOG.debug("Posting retrieved 'cis_party_change' msg with publishTimeStamp " + currentRecordTime + "and endTimeStamp is " + endTimeStamp);
                        originalTopicChannel.send(message);
                    } else {
                        LOG.debug("Current record time is - " + currentRecordTime + " and endTimeStamp of reconEvent is  - " + endTimeStamp);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // this results in 'commit failed for offsets' error 
                try {
                    consumer.commitAsync(currentOffsets, (offsets, exp) -> {
                        if (exp != null)
                            LOG.error("Commit failed for offsets {} " + offsets, exp);
                    });
                } catch(Throwable e){}
            } while (!records.isEmpty() && currentRecordTime < endTimeStamp);
        } catch(Exception exp) {
            LOG.error("Unexpected error", exp);
        } finally {
            //The below ALWAYS fails due to same groupAuthorizationexception and log.info is never reached
            //consumer.commitSync(currentOffsets);
            LOG.info("End of method - processPartition, consumer.commitSync completed");
        }
        return messages;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like your broker is configured with some policy to disallow these consumer groups; talk to your broker administrator. In any case, it looks like you are using a random group each time `random-groupid_ee10697f-e35f-4542-801c-1605620c59fa` so why do you need to commit offsets anyway? The group will be different the next time the app starts.

Comment: @GaryRussell - I did think it was a permission issue, but why would it allow me to 'create' the consumers, and perform seek, poll, etc operations? Only the 'close' and 'commit' operations throw this error. Also, the above code is part of spring-bean, so everytime the method is called, a new consumer is created with a unique group id. Only the 'time window' changes (start and endtime)...

Comment: I don't know; ask you admins - maybe you have read permissions, but not write?